# Is it possible to store messages in a socketio chat app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, socket.io

Let's say I made a complete UI of a chat app. We have a panel which contains all the recently contacted. We have react on the front-end and node, express on the backend. The real time data transfer chat is carried out using socketio.

The real question is how do I store all the messages that I have with each user. Let's say I chatted with user A for a while, closed the tab and moved to user B. Then the next day I moved back to the user A, I want all my previous chats with that user to be available to me.

How is that achievable?

One way I can wrap my head around is that I use mongoDB to create a chat room with two specific user and a id. Then I store that room on mongo with all the chats stored in an array.

On the client side, I check the db if a specific chat room exists. If it does, I send all the messages in  to the client side, if not it create a new chat room.

This is by far the most sensible thing I've thought.

Any guidance as to what other techniques I can use?

Much appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting the recently contacted ? Where is it been saved ?

Comment: Let's just say that for every "Chat with user I click", it sends that user id to a specific collection.

Comment: But forget about that the storing chat messages are the main problem